# Python why i get tuple and how to avoid it

Tags: python

I dont know why but i get tuple when i calculate AIQhum in this case hum is >42 and i got this tuple (0, 190669.42) dont know why i get the 0 in the first place. How can avoid it forcing to not getting tuple just the second value? Thank you.

```
   def getCO2(self):
    try:
        hum = sensor.data.humidity
        gas=0
        for x in range(10):
            gas= gas+sensor.data.gas_resistance

        gasAvr=gas/10

        if hum < 38:
            AIQhum = -0, 625 * hum + 25

        if hum >= 38 and hum <= 42:
            AIQhum = 0

        if hum > 42:
            AIQhum = 0,4167 * hum - 16.667
        #time.sleep(30)
        print(gasAvr)
        if gasAvr > 50000:
            gasAvr = 50000
        if gasAvr < 5000:
            gasAvr = 5000
        IAQresistencia=-0.0017*gasAvr+83.33

        IAQglobal=AIQhum+IAQresistencia



        IAQ2=IAQglobal*5

        if IAQ2<=50:
            message="Good"
        if IAQ2>=51 and IAQ2<=100:
            message="Moderate"
        if IAQ2>=101 and IAQ2<=150:
            message="Unhealghy for sensitive groups"
        if IAQ2>=151 and IAQ2<=200:
            message="Unhealthy"
        if IAQ2>=201 and IAQ2<=300:
            message="Very Unhealthy"
        if IAQ2>=301 and IAQ2<=500:
            message="Hazarous"
```

Comment: Python uses the US/UK decimal number system of using the '.' to indicate the decimal point. Did you mean: `0.4167`? I see that you use: `-0.0017` below that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a couple of places you use a comma in place of a decimal point, eg  `0,4167` instead of  `0.4167`

The `0,4167` is interpreted as a tuple `(0, 4167)` or even `(0, 4167 * hum - 16, 667)`

You need to use `.` for decimal point, like: `(0.4167 * hum - 16.667)`

Comment: (0, 189332.47999999998, 667)

Comment: Yeah, the `0,4167` is interpreted as a tuple `(0, 4167)` or even `(0, 4167 * hum - 16, 667)`; you need to use `.` for decimal point, like `(0.4167 * hum - 16.667)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the ",". I changed it to "."  and it's working now.